# Get next byte or nil from standard input – Ruby

Tags: ruby, stream, stdin

I want to read one byte at a time from the standard input in ruby, however, if there is no new data available, I want the method to return immediately so each_byte etc. are not an option for me, as far as I can see, because they block program execution.

Ideally the method would me allow to do something like this:

```
byte = STDIN.next_byte_or_nil
if(byte)
#Process
else
#Do something else
end
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `read_nonblock` which throws an `Errno::WOULDBLOCK` exception if a read operations would block. So `STDIN.read_nonblock(1) rescue nil` will read a byte without blocking or return `nil`.

Since you only use the `nil` value to check whether the call was successful, you don't really need the `rescue nil` though:

```
begin
  byte = STDIN.read_nonblock(1)
  #Process
rescue Errno::WOULDBLOCK
  #Do something else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[getc](http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/getc) is the method you're looking for:

```
byte = STDIN.getc
if byte
  # Process
else
  # Do something else
end
```

Comment: Does not work for me. While the #Process part is executed correctly, the second part is never executed as getc waits for the user to actually type something, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [readbyte](http://apidock.com/ruby/ARGF/readbyte%20readbyte) to achieve your goal.

Comment: Same problem as with the other answer. It just blocks program execution until the user types something.

Comment: The presence of data that has been typed but not yet been read.